# How to pesistently configure a Macmini4,1 to boot after power failure?

Tags: power-management, reboot, efi, firmware, hardware

I do have a Macmini4,1 (2010) and I want to use it as a server so it will always start even after a power failure.

Please remind that I am running Ubuntu on it, not OS X.

Still, based on what I found online I tried these options, none being good:

- boot OS X recovery or installer, and run `pmset autorestart 1`
- boot OS X and configure autorestart in Configuration panel
- `setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0` on ubuntu.

None of these worked so far...

```
>lspci|grep LPC
00:03:0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
```

Comment: You can find your version using `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` from Linux.

Comment: Based on http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2011/09/mac-mini-rebooting-tweaks-setpci-s-01f0.html it seems that I need to run the setpci on `03` instead of `1f` for these models, but I tried this and also failed.

Comment: If you reset NVRAM and then boot the mini into OS X and `sudo pmset autorestart 1; sleep 20` and then pull the power once the SMC has settled after the short sleep, what happens when you plug power back in?

Comment: @mike something strange, it worked but only once, and without sudo because on recovery disk you are in a single user mode already, without sudo. I tried to power it off after while it was in grub menu, and after powering it on it doesn't restore. This makes me believe that something is reseting its state.

Comment: Some people recomended to reset the SMC but the proceduse seems qeid for macMini http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964 --- it seems just like a long power-cut, nothing special. Even so tried it too.

Comment: Even if I managed to find a better source of information with more specific registers for macmini 2010, it still does not work in my case. See http://www.mythic-beasts.com/support/macminicolo_howto.html

Comment: I guess I was concerned that the hardware wasn't working properly. I've never had issues with Mac Mini restarting after power loss when booting into OS X proper and don't expect it to work when booted to recovery. I keep a full install of OS X in SD card and boot to that when I need to test hardware to ensure SMC and reboot work regardless of the OS in the main HDD/SSD.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I found one command that works, but now I am going to test your approach which I like much more as it is persistent. I will be back with details, and hopefully a guide for other poor souls :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to execute:

```
setpci -s 00:03.0 0x7b.b=0x19
```

Be carefull that this line is for this model, for other models read the full article from http://www.mythic-beasts.com/support/macminicolo_howto.html

Also, put this in rc.local, for some strange reason it block the computer if I put it in `grub.cfg`

Comment: Link -> `404`... wonk, wonk.

Comment: Updated link: https://www.mythic-beasts.com/support/servers/colo/macminicolo_howto

Comment: @NuSkooler both links now 404.

Comment: Archived link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111233/how-to-pesistently-configure-a-macmini4-1-to-boot-after-power-failure